# Batch file to tell if python is installed

Tags: python, batch-file

I am writing a windows batch file, and I would like to know if there is a way to detect if python is properly installed on a computer.  I need to run a .py file from the batch file, but first I need to check (also within the batch file) if that extension if recognized and can be run, without knowing the full file path to "python.exe".  Can this be done?

Update:
For clarification, I have now learned that python is not currently in the path.  The suggestions involving "where python", and "python —version 2" don't work for me - I get an error stating "python is not recognized as an internal or external command, etc".  Thanks for the help so far, is there another way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: perhaps just try `where python` I could have given a proper answer, but your quetion is off topic as you show no attempts of your own.

Comment: It's not clear if by "properly installed" do you mean also exact version check etc or just a python executable. Also, if you are interested in cases where it's installed but not in the path etc.

Comment: Michael Heath, Thank you so much, that's just what I was looking for!  I knew there had to be a simple solution to this!  Can you post that as an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>nul 2>nul assoc .py && echo Associated|| echo Not available
```

This relies on no overrule by use of i.e. context menu "*Open With*" -> "*Choose default program*".

`errorlevel` also can be used to test:

```
>nul 2>nul assoc .py

if errorlevel 1 (
    echo Not available
) else (
    echo Associated
)
```

View `assoc /?` for detailed help on the command.

Answer (score 4):

Open notepad paste in the code below and then save it as a .bat file 
(Remember to select all files in the little dropdown when saving)

You can use the following to check if python v. 2 or above is detected:

```
python --version 2>NUL
if not errorlevel 0 goto ...
```

Where '...' is in case python is NOT detected.

Comment: I would rather do `if not errorlevel 0 ...`  but typically we do not answer off topic questions.